# Is it bad to recreate stack object after injected to class as pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

```c
// Example program
#include <iostream>

class Foo{

public:  
  Foo(int a):a(a){}
  void print(){
      printf("%d\n",a);
  }

private: 
  int a;

};

class Bar{
public:
  Bar(Foo* foo):foo(foo){}
  void print(){
    foo->print();
  }

private:
  Foo* foo;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f = {10};
  Bar b(&f);
  b.print();
  f = {20};
  b.print();
}
```

In the code above a Foo object shared with a Bar object can be recreated without that Bar knows about it.
Imagine I have to inject the bar object into a third class. Now I can update the foo dependency without having to create a new object of bar and the third class.

Is this pattern commonly used or not and does it violate some of the OOP principles?

Comment: Passing the pointer to an object residing on the stack is rarely a good idea. Apart from that, you can implement a setter to update the Foo* in Bar. But what is your use-case? Knowing a broader scope would certainly help in suggesting a suitable pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by _can be recreated_? Copy/move assignment operator does not "recreate" the object.

Comment: @ypnos what is wrong about passing pointers to objects on the stack around? As long as nobody calls `delete` on it (which anyhow should not be the case) I dont see the problem

Comment: There is inexperienced people that create an object on the stack, pass its pointer on and then put it in a container. Or objects that keep the pointer when the object goes out of scope. Things like that. I'm not saying it is something you never do if you know what you are doing. I often have the case where I have a Qt Q* thing on stack but Qt methods expect a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code does what you think it does.
I've added the default constructors and assign/operators to your Foo class with some logging to see what happens. These constructors are added automatically by the compilers unless you disable them explicitly. See the output [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zMyMMz).

What happens in

```
f = {20};
```

is that you construct a different Foo object then you move-assign it to the original instance.

In this case it's equivalent to

```
f.a = 20;  // Assuming we make a public.
```

In conclusion.
If your usage is just to change fields in the existing instance (through assign operators in this case). Then everything should work fine. This shouldn't necessarily invalidate OOP principles, unless you have assumptions that Bar.foo is constant or doesn't change. This is usually called composition and it's fairly common (your UI will contain various button instances that might be modified from other sources).

If you expect to change the implementation (say Foo is a virtual class and you want a different derivation to be substituted) then in your code you will need to have `Foo* f = new Foo(10);`. You will have copy of the pointer in `b` and the assignment will create a new class, that will not be update in `b` (something like `f = new FooDerived(20);`.

To make it work you need a Provider class (this is a OOP pattern). This would be something that gives you a `Foo`. The simplest one would be `Foo**`. But it's likely better to have something a bit more customizable.

That said for any serious work try to stay away from naked pointers (`Foo*`). Use unique_ptr or shared_ptr as appropriate to save yourself a lot of problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this pattern commonly used or not and does it violate some of the OOP principles?

I would say that such a structure should be carefully used.

Actually, in `Bar` you are just copying the pointer value. But if the given `Foo` created on the stack goes out of scope, then `Bar` is storing a dangling pointer.

Trying to dereference a dangling pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

> Is it bad to recreate stack object after injected to class as pointer?

Actually, as ***@DanielLangr*** mentioned, you did not have *"recreated"* the object, you just have reassigned its contents, so the object lifetime has not ended.
In your case, you're still fine.

Comment: Why the downvote ? I would be glad to know what I missed :)

Comment: sorry I fail to see the problem. I would not call it bad practice. Of course you have to take care that the object is still alive while others are using it, but other than that, whats wrong with it?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Agreed, I will revise what I wrote. It should have been a "warning" not a "this is bad".

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks for the explanation and for pointing out that point by the way. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this pattern commonly used or not and does it violate some of the OOP principles?

Yes, this is fairly common, and OK in your example.

You do have to be careful to ensure that `f` remains alive for the whole lifetime of `b`, which is the case in your example. If you were to copy `b`, you would also need to ensure the copy didn't outlive `f`.

The nice thing about the local variables of a function `func` is that they outlive any local variables of functions that `func` calls. Thus the local variables of `main` live for (almost) the whole program, only global variables outlive them.